# Pick an easter egg for chat.serverfault!

Tags: discussion, chat

On chat.meta.stackoverflow, there's a little easter egg where text entered as

> [status-blah]

will be rendered as a moderator only tag.

We'd like to do something similar, but specific to serverfault -- namely, **when you type a magic string, something amusing and in-joke-y for *serverfault.com* happens**, and it's visible to the entire chat room.

Do you have any ideas for anything server-fault-y we can do as an easter egg in chat.serverfault.com ?

Answer here, or in the dedicated chat room for this topic at http://chat.serverfault.com/rooms/31/pick-a-meme

Comment: It's moments like these I wish I was creative...

Comment: How about "[dismiss-system-notification-bar]"?

Comment: @squill - `[status-bydesign]`

Comment: I did a small double-take when I saw the OP's name on this one.

Comment: You might find something involving ASCII or non-binary data more appealing to most of this crowd.

Comment: @Warner see my answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

I was just reading through the chat transcript for the room, and I quite like the idea of

`rm -rf /`

doing something that appears to do something nasty, but perhaps to the end-user's session only? Perhaps pretend to purge the chat history and then crash Server Fault (perhaps bring up a BSOD (or a panic/halt if you don't want to mix operating system faults)).

Comment: I really like the idea of BBS era linenoise.

Comment: Nothing brings me back like a good fake NO CARRIER, or a long string of ^H^H^H^H^H^H.

Comment: This is funny, but probably too disruptive to implement. (Not too technically challenging to implement, mind you; I just think a lot of people would abuse it and cause everyone else to leave chat in frustration.)

Comment: It could be implemented to discourage abuse.  It's an easter egg, not a documented feature.

Comment: Noone said that the message had to end being sent to any of the users... although maybe that's the point?

Comment: @Farseeker: @Jeff's question says *"and it's visible to the entire chat room."*

Comment: I still like the idea of line noise!

Answer (score 4):

How about a favico-style icon in front of certain links? Say, Windows icon for Microsoft links, that kind of thing. Kind of like this:

[Thingy http://sysadmin1138.net/images/mickysoft.png](http://sysadmin1138.net/images/mickysoft.png)

Oo! I know! Some kind of animated lightbulb whenever anyone has "any [thoughts|ideas]?" in a message. We get that a lot.

Comment: ooo i like the light bulb idea!

Answer (score 3):

@gWaldo's answer made me think... I like the [blinkenlights](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/818/pick-an-easter-egg-for-chat-serverfault#819) and the [rm -rf /](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/818/pick-an-easter-egg-for-chat-serverfault#821), but, those are just two specific examples. As a frequent user of [chat.meta.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/) what I like best about the `[status-*]` easter egg is that you can use it for *anything*. Leading to very funny back-and-forths. blinkenlights would probably be just a single image, or maybe a small handful.

In the spirit of the easter egg taking arbitrary user input and doing something to it, how about using either `figlet` or `cowsay` or something?

Examples:

`serverfault-answer:Reboot Your Server!` produces:

```
  ____      _                 _    __   __               
 |  _ \ ___| |__   ___   ___ | |_  \ \ / /__  _   _ _ __ 
 | |_) / _ \ '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __|  \ V / _ \| | | | '__|
 |  _ <  __/ |_) | (_) | (_) | |_    | | (_) | |_| | |   
 |_| \_\___|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|   |_|\___/ \__,_|_|   

  ____                           _ 
 / ___|  ___ _ ____   _____ _ __| |
 \___ \ / _ \ '__\ \ / / _ \ '__| |
  ___) |  __/ |   \ V /  __/ |  |_|
 |____/ \___|_|    \_/ \___|_|  (_)
```

Or:

```
 _____________________
< Reboot Your Server! >
 ---------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Comment: ASCII art, right up there with a fake NO CARRIER for bringing me back.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 yeah I was trying to think of something, well, sysadmin-y... ASCII art isn't exactly sysadminy, but it's the best I have come up with so far :-)

Comment: Could be prone to abuse but I like figlet.  Not a bad idea.  I use `sysvbanner` for a lot of my documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking something with blinkenlights..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights

Like some kind of light (image) with an optional text such as

> blinkenlights server overloaded

would produce something like..

[image]

.. (but more small single line icon-y) with the text "server overload" next to it

(from http://www.blinkenlights.nl/)

Comment: Not bad. Maybe it can print the optional text in binary lights?

Comment: I was going to downvote until I saw "(but more small single line icon-y)"; I'm not sure how well a standalone small blinkenlight would work, though.

Answer (score 1):

How about supporting changing the way usernames/gravatars/rep etc are displayed by typing something like `PS1=<something>`. also when you do this regular users have a '$' appended to their user name, and mods have '#' appended.

Comment: `prompt $p$g` aaah the memories

Answer (score 0):

```
MMMMMMMMMMMOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMOZMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMM8OMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOOMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMOOOMMMMMMMNNDDDNMMMMMMMMOOMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMM
MMMMM8OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMM
MMMM8OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOZMM
MMMMOOOOOOOOOOMMOMMMMMMMMO8MNOOOOOOOOOMM
MMMMOOOOOOO8MMMMOOOOOOOOOOOMMMN8OOOOOOOM
MMMMOOOOOOOOMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMOOOOOOOONM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOMMMMMMMMOOOODMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMM.    .OOO......MM.....O+..MM..MMMM
MMMMMM..8M..?O...MM .?M  =NOO+..MM  MMMM
MMMOOO.....:OO. MMM ..M  ...O+... ..MMMM
MMOZMM  8M  .O. MMM.  M  =8OO+..MM  MMMM
MO8MMM  ~,   O.  M: .MM  =OOO+..8M .MMMM
MOMMMM ....7OOOO...,MMM..~OOO+..OM. MMMM
MOMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMM
MOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MOOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMOZMMMMMMMMMMMMMMDNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMM8OODMMDOOOOOOO8ND8OOONMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMN88NMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOOMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOOMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOOMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMZOOOMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOONMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNOOOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

Answer (score 0):

How about involving the term

> Have you tried turning it off and on again?

.. for random questions? Not sure how it would work, but that quote solves about 90% of the questions right? :-)